# Socket-io can't handle more than 20 call per second

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to test an implementation of webcam streaming through socket-io.

I thought that socket-io could handle many requests per second but my flask server crash when I exceed about 20 call per second to my socket-io listener.

Here is the code in my website :

```js
setInterval(() => {
            socket.emit(
                "frame2server",
                `It is currently ${Date.now()}!`
            );
        }, 50); // 50ms = 20 fps
```

And here is the socket-io code :

```py
@socketio.on("frame2server")
def handle_frame(frame):
    socketio.emit("frame2client", frame)
```

Any ideas on the subject ?

Comment: how does it crash??

Comment: i found the answer finally!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because socket-io limits by default the number of calls per second. To fix that, you need to add :

```py
from engineio.payload import Payload

Payload.max_decode_packets = 50
```